# Can I link to the github page that filters in only my repositories?

Tags: github

In github, clicking on the *repositories* tab follows the URL https://github.com/yournamehere?tab=repositories.  Then clicking on the "sources" link causes the listing to include only those repositories that I have created, excluding others' repositories that I have forked.  Is there any way to generate a URL that will take a person immediately to that filtered list that contains my repos only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that page is coded, you can't directly navigate to that page.

If you want to exclude your forked repositories, you can [search repositories](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/#search-based-on-the-number-of-forks-the-parent-repository-has) and exclude forks.  `fork:false`.

So this should be what you are looking for

```
https://github.com/search?q=user%3Ayournamehere+fork%3Afalse
```

Comment: Sorry you had to wait so long for an answer. :)